# Fill Cascading Drodown from file names in a folder php

Tags: php, arrays, drop-down-menu

I have number of files in a Folder and I am looking to fill dropdowns in a website(local host) with Files names available in the folder.

File names are like below

> SL_400_M_STDS_ALL_F1161_LIFT.pdf and
>   AR_300_J_SYS_A_K1100_UP.pdf

As per the file name, there are 7 dropdowns , and it will not change.

Sorry, I am new to PHP, that's y I won't be able to paste any code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

try out this code :

```
<select name="s1">
      <option value="" selected="selected">select file</option>
  <?php 
       $dir = "files/*";// the files location form php file
       foreach(glob($dir) as $filename){
       $filename = basename($filename);
       echo "<option value='" . $filename . "'>".$filename."</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
```

[image]

best luck ..